# Angular Unit Test including FileReader.onload doesn't work with async/whenStable nor fakeAsync/tick

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, filereader

I'm adding some unit tests to my angular 7 app but I'm not sure how to handle the interaction with a FileReader since using async/whenStable, fakeAsync and promises don't work as expected.

- **The behavior I'm testing**: I need to verify the service `documentService.sendDocument` is called once a file is uploaded.

### **1st Approach**:

Before I found issues testing FileReader.onload I just tried to test it without async.

**Controller Code**

```
onFileGovernmentIdChange(event) {
    console.log('::: Init onFileGovernmentIdChange');
    const updateFunction = () => {
        console.log('::: BEFORE update fileGovernmentIdUploaded - ', this.fileGovernmentIdUploaded);
        this.fileGovernmentIdUploaded = true;
        console.log('::: AFTER update fileGovernmentIdUploaded - ', this.fileGovernmentIdUploaded);
    }
    this.saveFileFromInputSimple(event, DOCUMENT_TYPE.STORE_GOVERNMENT_ID, updateFunction);
    console.log('::: End onFileGovernmentIdChange');
}

private saveFileFromInputSimple(event, documentType: DOCUMENT_TYPE, updateState: () => any) {
    console.log('::: Init saveFileFromInputSimple');
    const reader = new FileReader();

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
        console.log('::: Event with files...');
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        reader.onload = () => {
            this.documentService
                .sendDocument(file.name, file.type, reader.result.toString(), documentType)
                .subscribe(
                    response => {
                        console.log('::: sendDocument - Subscribe OK');
                        updateState()
                    },
                    error => {
                        console.log('::: sendDocument - Subscribe ERROR');
                        this.showDefaultErrorDialog()
                    }
                );
        };
        console.log('::: Onload callback assigned...');
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    console.log('::: End saveFileFromInputSimple');
}
```

**UnitTest spec code**

```
fit('simple testing', () => {
    const documentService = TestBed.get(DocumentsService);
    const catalogService: CatalogService = TestBed.get(CatalogService);
    const customEvent = {
        target: {
            files: [new Blob(['ssdfsdgdjghdslkjghdjg'], { type: 'pdf' })]
        }
    };

    const commerceResponse = new CommerceResponse();
    commerceResponse.commissionPercentage = '11';

    spyOn(catalogService, 'getCatalog').and.returnValue(of({ catalogs: [] }));
    spyOn(documentService, 'getCommerceInfo').and.returnValue(of(commerceResponse));
    spyOn(documentService, 'sendDocument').and.returnValue(of({ response: 'ok' }));

    fixture.detectChanges();//Apply onInit changes
    console.log('::: Before calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()');
    component.onFileGovernmentIdChange(customEvent);
    console.log('::: After calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()');
    console.log('::: Before expects... ');
    expect(component.fileGovernmentIdUploaded).toBeTruthy();
    // expect(documentService.sendDocument).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    console.log('::: After expects... ');
});
```

**UnitTest result**

```
LOG: '::: Before calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()'
LOG: '::: Init onFileGovernmentIdChange'
LOG: '::: Init saveFileFromInputSimple'
LOG: '::: Event with files...'
LOG: '::: Onload callback assigned...'
LOG: '::: End saveFileFromInputSimple'
LOG: '::: End onFileGovernmentIdChange'
LOG: '::: After calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()'
LOG: '::: Before expects... '
LOG: '::: After expects... '
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Mac OS X 10.13.6) DocumentsComponent simple testing FAILED
        Expected undefined to be truthy.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/documents/documents.component.spec.ts:146:52)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:288:1)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)
```

**UnitTest analysis**

The code inside the `onload` method is never executed

### **2nd Approach**

Testing FileReader.onload without Observers: Just to follow the workflow I removed the Observer inside the `onload` to verify if that could be the problem.

**Controller Code**

```
private saveFileFromInputSimple(event, documentType: DOCUMENT_TYPE, updateState: () => any) {
    console.log('::: Init saveFileFromInputSimple');
    const reader = new FileReader();

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
        console.log('::: Event with files...');
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        reader.onload = () => {
            console.log('::: ONLOAD executed');
        };
        console.log('::: Onload callback assigned...');
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    console.log('::: End saveFileFromInputSimple');
}
```

**UnitTest spec code**

Same as 1st approach

**UnitTest result**

```
LOG: '::: Before calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()'
LOG: '::: Init onFileGovernmentIdChange'
LOG: '::: Init saveFileFromInputSimple'
LOG: '::: Event with files...'
LOG: '::: Onload callback assigned...'
LOG: '::: End saveFileFromInputSimple'
LOG: '::: End onFileGovernmentIdChange'
LOG: '::: After calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()'
LOG: '::: Before expects... '
LOG: '::: After expects... '
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Mac OS X 10.13.6) DocumentsComponent simple testing FAILED
        Expected undefined to be truthy.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/documents/documents.component.spec.ts:146:52)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:288:1)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Mac OS X 10.13.6): Executed 1 of 46 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.314 secs)
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Mac OS X 10.13.6) DocumentsComponent simple testing FAILED
        Expected undefined to be truthy.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/documents/documents.component.spec.ts:146:52)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:288:1)
LOG: '::: ONLOAD executed'
```

**UnitTest analysis**

Now the code in the `onload` method is executed but looks like an async operation because it was executed at the end.

### **3rd Approach**

Testing FileReader.onload with async unit test: As I found some kind of async operation I included the `async/fixture.whenStable` angular combination to wait for async code completion.

**Controller Code**

Same as 2nd approach

**UnitTest spec code**

```
fit('Testing with async/fixture.whenStable', async(() => {
    const documentService = TestBed.get(DocumentsService);
    const catalogService: CatalogService = TestBed.get(CatalogService);
    const customEvent = {
        target: {
            files: [new Blob(['ssdfsdgdjghdslkjghdjg'], { type: 'pdf' })]
        }
    };

    const commerceResponse = new CommerceResponse();
    commerceResponse.commissionPercentage = '11';

    spyOn(catalogService, 'getCatalog').and.returnValue(of({ catalogs: [] }));
    spyOn(documentService, 'getCommerceInfo').and.returnValue(of(commerceResponse));
    spyOn(documentService, 'sendDocument').and.returnValue(of({ response: 'ok' }));

    fixture.detectChanges();//Apply onInit changes
    console.log('::: Before calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()');
    component.onFileGovernmentIdChange(customEvent);
    console.log('::: After calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()');
    console.log('::: Before expects... ');

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        console.log('::: whenStable Init');
        expect(component.fileGovernmentIdUploaded).toBeTruthy();
        // expect(documentService.sendDocument).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        console.log('::: whenStable End');
    });

    console.log('::: After expects... ');
}));
```

**UnitTest result**

```
LOG: '::: Before calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()'
LOG: '::: Init onFileGovernmentIdChange'
LOG: '::: Init saveFileFromInputSimple'
LOG: '::: Event with files...'
LOG: '::: Onload callback assigned...'
LOG: '::: End saveFileFromInputSimple'
LOG: '::: End onFileGovernmentIdChange'
LOG: '::: After calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()'
LOG: '::: Before expects... '
LOG: '::: After expects... '
LOG: '::: whenStable Init'
LOG: '::: whenStable End'
**LOG: '::: ONLOAD executed'**
```

**UnitTest analysis**

As expected, the whenStable code is executed when the method has finished, however, the `onload` method continues executing at the end.
Googling I found that could be better to wrap the onload part in a Promise to be sure it's tracked by Angular async.

### **4th Approach**:

Wrap the `onload` in a promise and verify it works with the `async/whenStable` structure.

**Controller Code**

```
private readFileAsync(file): Promise<string> {
    console.log('::: readFileAsync Init');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            console.log(':::: Promise Resolved in ONLOAD')
            resolve(reader.result.toString());
        }
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}

private saveFileFromInputWithPromise(event, documentType: DOCUMENT_TYPE, updateState: () => any) {
    console.log('::: Init saveFileFromInputWithPromise');

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
        console.log('::: Event with files...');
        const file = event.target.files[0];

        this.readFileAsync(file)
            .then(fileContent => {
                console.log('::: File with content', fileContent);
                updateState();
            }).catch(error => console.log('::: File load error', error));
    }
    console.log('::: End saveFileFromInputWithPromise');
}
```

**UnitTest spec code**

Same as 3rd approach

**UnitTest result**

```
LOG: '::: Before calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()'
LOG: '::: Init onFileGovernmentIdChange'
LOG: '::: Init saveFileFromInputWithPromise'
LOG: '::: Event with files...'
LOG: '::: readFileAsync Init'
LOG: '::: End saveFileFromInputWithPromise'
LOG: '::: End onFileGovernmentIdChange'
LOG: '::: After calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()'
LOG: '::: Before expects... '
LOG: '::: After expects... '
LOG: '::: whenStable Init'
LOG: '::: whenStable End'
LOG: ':::: Promise Resolved in ONLOAD'
LOG: '::: File with content', 'data:pdf;base64,c3NkZnNkZ2RqZ2hkc2xramdoZGpn'
LOG: '::: BEFORE update fileGovernmentIdUploaded - ', undefined
LOG: '::: AFTER update fileGovernmentIdUploaded - ', true
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Mac OS X 10.13.6) DocumentsComponent Testing with async/fixture.whenStable FAILED
        Expected undefined to be truthy.
            at http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/documents/documents.component.spec.ts:176:56
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
            at AsyncTestZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:713:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:285:1)
```

**UnitTest analysis**

Again the Promise is resolved after the `whenStable` function.

### **5th Approach**:

As the `async/whenStable` didn't work as expected I tried changing to `fakeAsync/tick/flush` structure.

**Controller Code**

Same as 4th Approach (Including `onload` in a promise)

**UnitTest spec code**

```
fit('Testing with fakeAsync/tick/flush', fakeAsync(() => {
    const documentService = TestBed.get(DocumentsService);
    const catalogService: CatalogService = TestBed.get(CatalogService);
    const customEvent = {
        target: {
            files: [new Blob(['ssdfsdgdjghdslkjghdjg'], { type: 'pdf' })]
        }
    };

    const commerceResponse = new CommerceResponse();
    commerceResponse.commissionPercentage = '11';

    spyOn(catalogService, 'getCatalog').and.returnValue(of({ catalogs: [] }));
    spyOn(documentService, 'getCommerceInfo').and.returnValue(of(commerceResponse));
    spyOn(documentService, 'sendDocument').and.returnValue(of({ response: 'ok' }));

    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log('::: Before calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()');
    component.onFileGovernmentIdChange(customEvent);
    console.log('::: After calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()');
    console.log('::: Before expects... ');

    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    flushMicrotasks();
    flush();
    console.log('::: After Flush Init');
    expect(component.fileGovernmentIdUploaded).toBeTruthy();
    // expect(documentService.sendDocument).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    console.log('::: After Flush End');
    console.log('::: After expects... ');
}));
```

**UnitTest result**

```
LOG: '::: Before calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()
LOG: '::: Init onFileGovernmentIdChange'
LOG: '::: Init saveFileFromInputWithPromise'
LOG: '::: Event with files...'
LOG: '::: readFileAsync Init'
LOG: '::: End saveFileFromInputWithPromise'
LOG: '::: End onFileGovernmentIdChange'
LOG: '::: After calling onFileGovernmentIdChange()'
LOG: '::: Before expects... '
LOG: '::: After Flush Init'
LOG: '::: After Flush End'
LOG: '::: After expects... '
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Mac OS X 10.13.6) DocumentsComponent Testing with async/fixture.whenStable FAILED
        Expected undefined to be truthy.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/documents/documents.component.spec.ts:211:52)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:1424:1)
            at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:288:1)
LOG: ':::: Promise Resolved in ONLOAD'
LOG: '::: File with content', 'data:pdf;base64,c3NkZnNkZ2RqZ2hkc2xramdoZGpn'
LOG: '::: BEFORE update fileGovernmentIdUploaded - ', undefined
LOG: '::: AFTER update fileGovernmentIdUploaded - ', true
```

**UnitTest analysis**

Again, the Promise is resolved after the fakeAsync/tick/flushMicrotasks/flush structure

#### What is wrong?

I followed every tutorial I found and every different approach trying to include the `FileReader.onload` in my test (as that method call the service I want to spy and verify) but always the method resolve after the async blocks provided by Angular. I saw other approaches where the `window.fileReader` is mocked but that's not the purpose of my test.

So could anybody tell me what is wrong in my code or in the way I'm testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great post, perfectly describing my evening.

It seems it is a known issue that fakeAsync does not support FileReader, as "it is not fundamentaly a timer related async operation".

See: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1120

Comment: This drove me insane!